# Force to compress previously supported spring?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, spring

Let's assume I have a spring with k = 1 kN/m, an uncompressed length of 2.0 m, and a compressed length of 1.0 m (i.e. 1 kN of force to fully compress the spring.)
[image: a visual of the spring compressed, uncompressed, and in a cylinder]

If I put that spring into a pneumatic cylinder which requires the spring be compressed by 0.5 m during assembly (the 0.5 kN of force being supported by the top and bottom walls of the cylinder), how much force is required to compress the spring the remainder of the way?

My understanding is that it would still require the full 1.0 kN of force to fully compress the spring, because as soon as the top of the spring moves off of the top of the cylinder the full spring force must be supported by the applied force.

(I am trying to determine how systems like [this](https://www.kurtworkholding.com/product/vb-docklock-flanged-cylinder/) can claim to have 2,000+ lbs of clamping force while being able to release that force with minimal air pressure. The simple F = P*A says that the area of the air cylinder would need to be *much* larger than the diameter of the device to be able to release that kind of force.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, spring force is only related to deflection amount. If the free length is 2m and you compress it to 1.5m to install you need $F = \frac{2-1.5}{k} = 500 N$ of force.

Now to compress it further to 1m you need $F = \frac{2-1.0}{k} = 1000 N$ of force.